graphite logs full of messages like "Couldn't match metric navi.memory.memory.free with any aggregation rule. Passing on un-aggregated."
I have collectd running that send data to carbon via the write_graphite plugin.
I use the docker-graphite-statsd image to run graphite.
Looking at logs of the container I get a lot of these message, every time the data is send,
for example but this is for every type of metric.
[console] Couldn't match metric myhost.cpu.1.cpu.nice with any aggregation rule. Passing on un-aggregated.

Is this an error or a warning?
I have logs full of these messages.
Is there something that I miss on configuration?

Found the problem, I was using the wrong port.
I was using 2023 carbon aggregator - plaintext⁠ but the right one, for my case is 2003 carbon receiver - plaintext⁠.
As a note, before finding the port problem, I found in carbon.conf the setting LOG_AGGREGATOR_MISSES, if set to True will disable the logs messages that I wrote in my question but the solution is to use the right port.
